# How to check if a resource is translated for a language

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to do some control flow logic based on whether there is a translation available for a specific resource in the current culture's language.

I tried using `ResourceManager.GetString()` to look up the resource in my desired culture, but it returns the resource in the default language if it's not translated - and there is no way to figure out if the resource is translated or not.

Comment: Why don;t you just check against the default (non-translated) language? For example `bool isTranslated = ResourceManager.GetString("something", "es-es") /*translated*/ == ResourceManager.GetString("something", "en-us") /*NOT translated*/;

Comment: This is graceful degradation. If the translation is not available, it does the best it can. You can never have full translations for all languages.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath because the default language translation might be a valid translation for some other language's translation as well, for example they might be the same for en-uk and en-us etc.

Comment: @Sheagorath or even `en-GB` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional resource string that is not used in your UI, but only to determine whether the translation is available.
For example, the string content in the default language could be "Default", and in each Translation it could be "Translated".
Then you can check in your code whether the string has the content "Default" and base your control flow logic on that.